# Drupal 7.34 install error Call to undefined function field_read_fields()

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I keep getting this error when trying to do a fresh install of 7.34 in a sub directory.

An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging information follows. Path: http://tristarprotector.com/drupalbeta/install.php?profile=standard&locale=en&id=1&op=do StatusText: OK ResponseText: Fatal error: Call to undefined function field_read_fields() in /home/content/32/10158732/html/drupalbeta/modules/field/modules/field_sql_storage/field_sql_storage.install on line 16

Any idea what is causing this or how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have the file: /modules/field/field.crud.inc? That is where the field_read_fields function is.

Comment: yes I do have that file in that directory along with several others.

Comment: Did you ever get this solved? I'm encountering the same thing.

Comment: @jay this was awhile ago so I am trying to recall. I think I just moved the install to a different place to get it working but honestly my memory is kinda fuzzy on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.

Fixed it by rebooting the server in the end (just a vbox), apache restart didn't fix it.